# Removing unwanted characters from arraylist? Java

Tags: java, arraylist, character, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to save the contents of an ArrayList to a txt file but when I do this I'm getting a lot of unwanted characters. Comma's I can deal with with string.replace() but I'm just wondering if theres another way to filter these types of characters more efficiently? especially the "¬í t[" part in the txt file. There are also other characters that are displayed in the above quotation marks but it wont let me copy them here. My code to output to file is below. I am adding several strings to the ArrayList but the problem seems to be with the array list itself. As shown below I have converted the list to a string and printed to file this way as I seem to get less unwanted characters. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
String Output = ScanOutputList.toString();
FileOutputStream fstream = new FileOutputStream("Port_Scan.txt");
ObjectOutputStream ostream = new ObjectOutputStream(fstream);

ostream.writeObject(Output);
ostream.close();
```

Comment: What is the elements' class inside the ArrayList? Has it got a toString() function defined?

Comment: The only way I can think of is for you to specify in your code exactly which characters to exclude, which could lead to you writing a rather long and nasty if statement.  Might it be easier to specify which characters to include?

Comment: Also, instead of writing the String using an ObjectOutputStream->FileOutputStream, use a FileWriter. This one can accept String and writes them to the file as is (using default encoding).

Answer (score 0):

If some wierd characters are your main problem and you simply want to get rid of everything that isn't "standard" character, what you could do is cast your strings char arrays and then cast those chars to ints. If given int is too big, remove it. Lastly - recreate your strings from those int which haven't been removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write text to a file (as indicated by the .txt extension), don't use output streams.  Use writers:

FileWriter fw = null;

```
try {
   fw = new FileWriter(file);
   fw.print(StringUtils.join(collection, System.getProperty("line.separator")));
}
finally {
   IOUtils.closeQuietly(fw);
}
```

I also wouldn't use the "toString" method on the list, as it gives you the format:

```
[ item1.toString(), item2.toString() ]
```

It's better to put things in the format you want.  The above code would put 1 item per line, and put a line break (system dependent) in between each one.

As mentioned above, the type of object in the list is important too, because it would use the "toString()" method when writing the object.  You could do custom output by replacing the StringUtils.join with a for loop, and writing exactly what you want in the loop.

Comment: ps:  I'm assuming you're using commons-lang and commons-io packages which is where StringUtils and IOUtils classes reside.